# Getting Content Encoding Error when i enable Gzip Page Compression on joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I am getting Content Encoding Error when I am enabling the Gzip Page Compression on my Joomla website , how can I enable this without this error?

Comment: Is it 1.5 or 3.2? Also what actual error? This is really not enough information.

Comment: Its joomla 3.2 and i am getting "Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem." this error when i open the web site . if i refresh the website its coming properly . please help me to find the problem

Comment: Is this in all browsers?

Comment: I am getting this when trying to optimize a 3 site, on the forum its noted as a FireFox problem (since v2.x at least). I get it only when try add new article in FF. Would be nice to have solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that your server already has gzip compression turned on. When the server gzips, then Joomla tries to gzip again it can cause some weird encoding issues. Contact your hosting company and find out if they gzip automatically. If so, there is no need to have it on in Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had the same problem as me and actually have **some utf-8 files WITH an UTF-8 BOM inside** * in your code or joomla files somehow.
I think gzip in combination with UTF-8 BOM gives an encoding problem.

***Note:***
 - Not all editors are able to show if the BOM is there or not.  I had to actually use another editor, Notepad++, to realize there was a BOM there and remove it there via "Convert to utf-8 without BOM" and then saving the file. (Also closing it in my original editor first.)
But could as well be that you can set your editor not to include the BOM.
 - Possibly this only occurs when php error reporting is on

* *More about UTF BOM:*

- stackoverflow: [What's different between utf-8 and utf-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)
- Wikipedia: [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)